# Combine 2 lists on items where string matches between lists

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 2 `List<string>`s that contain a list of network names.

```
List<string> nets1 = new List<string>() { "net1", "net2", "net3" };
List<string> nets2 = new List<string>() { "net2", "net3", "net4" };
```

I want to combine them into a new `List<string>`, but only where the `string`s are equal. So my desired result will be of type `List<string>` and contain ONLY `net2` and `net3`.

I have tried to use Union and Concat but they dont seem to be what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var list = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: 13 secs fast :P

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for the common elements in both list, you can use [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var commonElements = nets1.Intersect(nets2).ToList();
```